# Database update for an e commerce portal taking time with php cron script

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron, e-commerce

I am trying to update the database of an e commerce website with a php cron script in linux server.The cron is update products in a table where the number of products are around 1200000.The problem is cron is taking almost one day to complete the cron sript,which is very much.

Please tell me the points on how can i reduce the cron script updation time to 2-3 hours or less than that.

Database- Mysql
Language-Php
Server-Linux

Answer (score 0):

1. Use multiple processes that will each treat a subset of products. You can do that with pnctl or just launch your script multiple times passing parameter to tell where to start for example.
2. If you are doing inserts, you can do mass insert instead of 1 insert per sql query.
3. See if anything can be optimized in your algorithm (e.g. by using caching or reducing its complexity). However, i guess you already tried that.

Comment: for your first point,I tried to update the product list based on some categories list in one cron,lets say 5 categories in one cron.But then i wanted to run cron for full category list for which data i m getting from third party web service call.Second point i can perform.But most of results are to be updated.Third point i didnt get fully.Please elaborate that..

Comment: Basically, look for opportunities to simplify (less loops for example) and/or increase performance of the code (e.g. locate what part of the code is taking the longest and see if anything could be optimized). Let's say you do a webservice call for each product to get some data needed when updating the DB, see if you could do 1 webservice call for multiple products.

Comment: There is only one web service call happening currently for list of products.after getting the complete list only i m starting the db update process in script